# Получить json после ajax с преминением promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

Есть функция, которая на входе принимает `id` затем посылает его на сервер, после чего в качестве ответа я получаю выборку и базы. Все хорошо работает.

Появилась необходимость использовать эти данные все функции, воспользовался `promise`

```
var productinfo = function(id) {
                  var promise = $.ajax({
                    dataType: "JSON",  
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "serverscript/jsonproduct.php",
                    data: "id="+id,
                  })

                  return promise.done(function(data) {
                    return data

                  })
            }
```

затем вызываю ее

```
console.log(productinfo(id))
```

Получаю такой массив

```
abort:
always
complete
done
error
fail
getAllResponseHeaders
getResponseHeader
overrideMimeType
pipe
progress
promise
readyState
responseJSON
....
```

По сути то,что мне необходимо в дальнейшем использовать тут `responseJSON`
Пробовал достать так

```
return promise.done(function(data) {
        return data.responseJSON;
    })
```

Но видимо где-то ошибся,так как возвращает тоже самое.А не нужное мне.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не возвращает `.done` то, что Вы возвращаете из функции, которую туда подаете в качестве параметра. Возвращать что-то из этой функции бессмысленно. `.done` возвращается сразу (и возвращает тот же самый `promise`) - он всего лишь запоминает функцию, которую Вы туда подали, чтобы вызвать ее, когда "обещание" (promise) исполнится.

Не могут у Вас в коде появится данные, получаемые асинхронно, **до** того, как придет ответ на запрос.

```
var productinfo = function(id, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "JSON",  
    type: 'POST',
    url: "serverscript/jsonproduct.php",
    data: "id="+id,
    success: callback
  });
}

productinfo(id, function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

Comment: То есть сам `promise` переписать?

Comment: Не понял вопроса.

Comment: По сути  нарушена логика, нужно переделать момент возврата данных?

Comment: @zkolya Добавил вариант.

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь понял как это решать. Вы очень помогли. Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Очень прошу, в 2018 (почти) году не писать код с коллбеками, тем более на фронтенде..  (как предложено в другом ответе). Если Вы хотите использовать jQuery, хотя для этой задачи (опять же в почти-2018-м году), то можете обернуть его в промис вот так.

Сразу отмечу, что данная проблема и лишний код появляется потому, что используется jQuery для запросов, хотя есть fetch и полифилы к нему

Вариант 1:

```
const getProductInfo = id => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const params = {
      dataType: "JSON",
      type: 'POST',
      url: "serverscript/jsonproduct.php",
      data: "id="+id,
  };

  $.ajax(params)
    .done(data => resolve(data.responseJSON))
    .fail(() => reject('Failed'));
});

// later on..

try {
  const productInfo = await getProductInfo('123');
}
catch (e) {
  // react to error
}
```

Вариант 2 (удобнее):

```
const getProductInfo = id => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const params = {
      dataType: "JSON",
      type: 'POST',
      url: "serverscript/jsonproduct.php",
      data: "id="+id,
  };

  $.ajax(params)
    .done(data => resolve(data.responseJSON))
    .fail(() => resolve(null));
});

const productInfo = await getProductInfo('123');

if (!productInfo) {
  console.log('error');
}
```

Если нет возможности использовать async/await:

```
getProductInfo('123')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.log);
```

Вариант с `fetch`

```
const getProductInfo = id => fetch('/url.json', {
  method: 'POST'
})
  .then(data => data.json())
  .catch(e => null);

const productInfo = await getProductInfo('123');

if (!productInfo) {
  // log error
}
```